# AuthorizationContext vs AuthorizationHandlerContext in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

The ASP.NET Core article titled “[Custom Policy-Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html?highlight=authorizationcontext)” sample code passes a **AuthorizationContext** parameter into **HandleRequirementAsync()** methods.

- The sample sample code will not compile without implementing (or referencing) AuthorizationContext.
- I found 4 AuthorizationContext classes, none of which are included in the .NET Platform Standard (per https://apisof.net on 9/17/16).
- I could not find AuthorizationContext in the  aspnet/Identity GitHub repository (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AuthorizationContext).
- The only relavent sample code that I could find was using AuthorizationHandlerContext (https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop/blob/master/src/Workshop_Suggested_Solution/AlbumOwnerAuthorizationHandler.cs).

Will someone please clarify **AuthorizationContext** vs **AuthorizationHandlerContext** and how to implement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems `AuthorizationContext` is old name of `AuthorizationHandlerContext` . You should use `AuthorizationHandlerContext`. See https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/819